# Transformation of derivatives of coordinates

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

I am quite new to this topic. Please bear with me.

Suppose we are given a transformation of both time and space coordinate's derivatives as
$$
\partial_t\to D_t=\partial_t-f(t,x)\partial_t\\
\nabla\to \mathbf{D}=\nabla+\mathbf{F}(t,x)\partial_t \tag{1}
$$
$f$ is a scalar field and $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field. Is there anyway to know what kind of coordinate transformation made the derivative transformation look like $(1)$?

Personally, the time derivative transformation given in $(1)$ looks okay to me but the space derivative transformation looks "weird" to me. I mean the space derivative is changing into time derivative... what does it mean? Is it a normal thing? Could someone please explain what is the physical meaning of this transformation.

Answer (score 3):

I can’t explain the physical meaning for all $f$ but I can say that Lorentz transformations also mix time and space derivatives so in a sense this is normal. This is because the  [derivative $\partial^\mu$ 4-vector is well… a 4-vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528583/is-the-four-gradient-of-a-scalar-field-a-four-vector) so it transforms under Lorentz transformations like $x^\mu$.

What is the meaning of mixing time and space derivatives in special relativity frame transformations?

From an unnamed resource online:

> Comparing to Galilean transformations, the Lorentz transformation
> mixes space and time coordinates between the two frames so we cannot
> arbitrarily dissociate the two types of coordinates. The basic unit in
> space-time is now an event, which is specified by a location in space
> and time given in relation to any system of reference. This mixture of
> space and time makes it evident that we must abandon our cherished and
> intuitive notion of absolute time.

With that in mind, if we take the typical 1D $x$-boost transformation (which now we are considering *needs* to mix space and time coordinates),
$$x' = x'(x,t)$$
Consider some function $f$ of $x'$. By the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial f(x')}{\partial t'} = \frac{\partial f(x')}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t'} +\frac{\partial f(x')}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial t'}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f(x')}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f(x')}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} +\frac{\partial f(x')}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x'}$$
so it is natural these derivatives mix when the coordinates mix (so the physical intuition follows from the quote above).

[Related Post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460934/transformation-of-4-velocity/470031#470031).